# Given a day name in a string, how can I get a Time object representing that day within the current week?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, time

Given a string with day name, i.e. `"Wednesday"`, how can I get a Time object representing that day within the current week (Monday - Sunday)?

So for example, if the current day is Tuesday 29 May, and the string is `"Monday"`, the time object should represent `Monday 28 May`. If the string is `"Friday"`, it should be `Friday 1 June`.

Whereas if the current day is Tuesday 5 June, and the string is `"Monday"`, the time object should represent `Monday 4 June`. If the string is `"Friday"`, it should be `Friday 8 June`.

I am using Rails 3.2.0 and Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a pretty handy gem for these types of textual date references called `Chronic`:
http://chronic.rubyforge.org/

For your purpose you could use the `"this week"` reference:

```
Chronic.parse("monday this week")
Chronic.parse("friday this week")
..etc..
```

..which should work pretty much as expected.

Comment: Note that Chronic's idea of "this week" runs Monday to Sunday.  So today, Tuesday May 29th, `Chronic.parse('monday this week')` returns yesterday (May 28th), but `Chronic.parse('sunday this week')` returns *next* Sunday (June 3rd).  That may or may not be what you had in mind.

Comment: Thanks..yes Ben specifically mentioned a Monday to Sunday type of week. So it will work correctly for him.

Comment: Whups, didn't see that parenthetical.  Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple enough to calculate, but you have to first parse the day names, which means you need a list of them:

```
WEEKDAY_NAMES = %w<Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday>
```

If you want to avoid hard-coding them (and even honor locale settings if you're still on Ruby 1.8), you can do this instead:

```
WEEKDAY_NAMES = (3..9).map { |i| Time.at( i * 86400 ).utc.strftime '%A' }
```

Then you can use logic like this to get the number:

```
wday = WEEKDAY_NAMES.each_with_index.find{|name,number|name == 'Wednesday'}[1]
```

Or, better, build up a hash of name->number pairs:

```
wday_from_name =  Hash[*WEEKDAY_NAMES.each_with_index.to_a.flatten]
wday = wday_from_name['Wednesday']
```

Once you have the target weekday in numeric form:

```
now = Time.now
wday_this_week = now + (wday - now.wday) * 86400
```

Unlike Chronic, this method considers weeks to run Sunday through Saturday (because that's how the `Time#wday` numbers work, with  0 meaning Sunday).  You can easily adjust that to use a different day as the first day of the week, however.

```
WEEK_START = wday_from_name['Monday']
wday_this_week = now + 
    ((wday - WEEK_START)%7 - (now.wday - WEEK_START)%7) * 86400
```

Since you're in Rails, you can use the ActiveSupport core extensions to make this a little bit prettier, with e.g.:

```
WEEKDAY_NAMES = (3..9).map { |i| Time.at( i.days ).utc.strftime '%A' }

wday_this_week = now + 
    ((wday - WEEK_START)%7 - (now.wday - WEEK_START)%7).days
```